Relative compactness of sequences and sets
I am currently solving an exercise that is concerned with relative compactness.

The space $C(X)$ is assumed is assumed to be equipped with the supremumnorm. My problem is with e). I concluded that $(h_n)$ is equicontinous and not relatively compact but I am in doubt regarding the correctness of my proof.
In order to show equicontinuity I did the following:
Let $x \in X$. Let $\varepsilon>0$. Choose $\delta:=\min \{1, \frac{\varepsilon}{L} \}$ where $L>1$. Assume $|x-y|<\delta$. Then for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ the mean value theorem implies that there is $x_0 \in (0, \infty)$ such that
$$
|h_n(x)-h_n(y)|
=|h_n'(x_0)| \ |x-y|
=\frac{1}{n} h_n(x_0) \ |x-y|
\leq \frac{1}{n} \ |x-y|
<L \ |x-y|
\leq L \ \frac{\varepsilon}{L}
=\varepsilon
$$
Then $(h_n)$ is equicontinous.
In order to show that $(h_n)$ is not relatively compact I wanted to show that it is not a Cauchy sequence w.r.t. the supremumnorm.
Let $\varepsilon=\frac{e-1}{e^3}$ and consider $N_0 \in \mathbb{N}$. Choose $x=N_0, n=N_0, m=2 \ N_0$. Then
$$
|h_n(x)-h_m(x)|
=|e^{-1}-e^{-\frac{1}{2}}|
=\frac{1-e}{e^2}
>\frac{1-e}{e^3}
=\varepsilon.
$$
So $(h_n)$ is not a Cauchy sequence w.r.t. the supremumnorm. Hence it cannot have a convergent subsequence, so the closure of $\{h_n \mid n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is not sequentially compact and therefore cannot be compact. Then $(h_n)$ cannot be relatively compact. Is my solution correct or is there an error?
